# how to use sshpass to a different port number

Tags: sshpass

I am trying to use sshpass with port number.

```
sshpass -p "somepassword" scp someuser@12.12.12.12/somefile /somefolder
```

how to pass port number to sshpass ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use sshpass with a port number, you can specify the port using the -P option. Here's how you can modify your command:

```
sshpass -p "somepassword" scp -P <port_number> someuser@12.12.12.12:/somefile /somefolder
```

Replace <port_number> with the actual port number you want to use. For example, if the port number is 2222, the command would be:

```
sshpass -p "somepassword" scp -P 2222 someuser@12.12.12.12:/somefile /somefolder
```

This will allow you to use sshpass with a specific port number for SCP.
The -P option in scp is used to specify the port number, and it is different from the -p option in sshpass. The -P option in scp is case-sensitive and should be in uppercase.
The default SSH port is 22, but you can specify a different port using the -P option in scp when using sshpass